# Dotnet core 2.1 extension method don't compile

Tags: .net-core

I'm trying to create an extension method in a dotnet core 2.1 application and it does not compile.

My Extension method:

```
 public static class ObjectExtension
 {
    public static bool IsNull(this Object object)
    {
        return Object.ReferenceEquals(object, null);
    }
 }
```

Error output:

> ObjectExtension.cs(7,47): error CS1001: Identifier expected ObjectExtension.cs(7,47): error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected ObjectExtension.cs(7,53): error CS1001: Identifier expected ObjectExtension.cs(9,43): error CS1525: Invalid expression term 'object'

Comment: Add @ to object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`object` is reserved word and cannot be used. please try to change it and compile again

Comment: If this answer is helpful for you please consider to mark it as answer

Answer (score 0):

Add `@` to `object`

```cs
    public static class ObjectExtension
    {
        public static bool IsNull(this Object @object)
        {
            return Object.ReferenceEquals(@object, null);
        }
    }
```